# Autocad won't let me saving

Tags: autocad, autolisp

Hello guys I've a big big problem.
I've installed something that prevent autocad from saving, dxfout and so on. Can't figure it out. I've tried to undefine and redefine commands, use the .save .saveas .dxfout but nothing works. When i perform these commands i got a notificatiom that a system var has been modify and then restored (maybe the filedia). 
I've tryed using vl-commands as well

```
`(vl-catch-all-apply
  'vla-SaveAs
    (list actDoc
(strcat(getvar "DWGPREFIX")
  (getvar "DWGNAME") "RECOVER")))`
```

What can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure filedia is set to 1. (if you want the normal dialog)

Try an underscore before the command. _.save _.saveas _.dxfout